# Segmentation fault while importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04

When I upgrade my tensorflow to 1.4,the question appears.That is
"Segmentation fault"
However my tensorflow(1.2)can work without any problem.

Comment: Please include more detailed error messages and as much detailed information as you can about your OS, application, and tensorflow versions.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 tensorflow1.4,